# How to prevent Android TextView from breaking text that follows a specific pattern into multiple lines?

Tags: android, textview, word-wrap

I'm creating an Android app, and I need to present some data. The data is in text format, and is going to be presented in a `TextView`, and here is an example of how it may be formatted:

> Some words, some words, even more/words

My problem is that when the sentence is long enough, the `TextView` automatically wraps the text into two lines. I want this line wrap to happen, but not at the place it is happening. The line wrap may be created at the space between *even* and *more/words*, or after the slash in *even more/words*,
but I want the line break to occur before this text (*even more/words*), after the comma. The same is for the spaces. **Basically, I want the text to not wrap into a new line on any other place than after any of the commas.**

Here are some examples on how the text might be wrapped, and how I want it instead in each case.

---

*Example*

> Some text, some text, some
>   more/text

*Wanted result*

> Some text, some text,
>   some more/text

---

*Example*

> Some text, some text, some more/
>   text

*Wanted result*

> Some text, some text,
>   some more/text

---

*Example*

> Some text, some
>   text, some more/
>   text

*Wanted result*

> Some text,
>   some text,
>   some more/
>   text

---

I looked through the Android source for the `TextView`-class and tried to find the place where the line wrapping was done, so that I could override that method and in some way add my own "rules" for it, but I couldn't find it. I also Googled for it, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Hope It's clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use
`Html.fromHtml("")` at the time of setting the text.

Example:

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("First line,<br/>Second line"))
```

Result:

> First line,
>
> Second line

Comment: This doesn't help, because I wan't this to happen automatically, so that it will fit as many "parts" (separated by commas) on one line, and when it is full, it creates a new line and places the next parts on.